Is there a more natural way to define the Young symmetrizer and the Specht module?
It's well known that Young symmetrizer is a fundamental tool in the representation theory of symmetric groups.
For instance, for every Young diagram $\lambda\vdash n$, we construct a Young tableau $T_\lambda$ by filling in the numbers $1,2,\ldots,n$ in increasing order, left to right, top to bottom. Then we define the two Young projectors
$$
a_{\lambda}:=\sum_{g\in P_{T_\lambda}}g\;\;,\quad b_{\lambda}:=\sum_{g\in Q_{T_\lambda}}(-1)^{g}g
$$
where $P_{T_\lambda}$ is the row stabilizer subgroup and $Q_{T_\lambda}$ is the column stabilizer subgroup. The Young symmetrizer is then defined as $c_\lambda:=a_\lambda b_\lambda$ and the Specht module is $V_\lambda:=\mathbb{C}[S_n]c_\lambda$. Every irreducible complex representations of $S_n$ is isomorphic to $V_\lambda$ for a unique $\lambda$.
However, I don’t quite understand how the definition of the Young symmetrizer is derived. Is there a more natural way to introduce this element?
To avoid the somewhat unnatural Young symmetrizer, I came across a beautiful and elementary approach to the theory of representation of $S_n$, developed by Okounkov and Vershik. In this framework, every irreducible representation $V^\lambda$ of $S_n$ is also associated with a Young diagram $\lambda$. However, this raises additional questions:
Is $V^\lambda$ in Okounkov-Vershik theory isomorphic to the Specht module $V_\lambda = \mathbb{C}[S_n] c_\lambda$? Can we rediscover the Young symmetrizer $c_\lambda$ in Okounkov-Vershik theory?
The sole answer to a similar question on MSE seems to treat Young symmetrizer as the key point to Schur-Weyl duality. Another question explores the characterization of the Specht module, which may provide additional insights.

There are many ways to define Specht modules (see the various "avatars" in my notes, and there are more I plan to add). The Okounkov-Vershik one is one of the less natural, as it only works in characteristic $0$ to the best of my knowledge. But yes, it is isomorphic to the Specht module. This should be in the book that I cite as [CSScTo10] in the above-linked notes.

[CSScTo10] on this matter follows Vershik's "A new approach to the representation theory of the symmetric groups, III." However, there is a gap in Vershik's argument, repeated in [CSScTo10]. The gap is explained in the bachelor's thesis of Matthew J Hall at the University of Arizona.

Isn't the idea that if you use just the row stabilizer, you get the action on words, corresponding to $h_\lambda$, which contains $s_\mu$ only if $\mu \leq \lambda$ in dominance order, whereas if you use just the column stabilizer you get the related $e_{\lambda'}$, which contains $s_{\mu'}$ only if $\mu' \leq \lambda'$? Then if you do both since conjugation reverses dominance order the only thing left is $\mu = \lambda$? I confess I never filled in the details.

If I'm not mistaken, the symmetrisers $c_\lambda = a_\lambda , b_\lambda$ have the drawback that they are not orthogonal. (I don't remember when the first counter-example shows up; it might be $n=6$ where the dominance order is no longer a total ordering.) The construction used by Okounkov--Vershik (which I believe was essentially already found by Young, On quantitative substitutional analysis VI, 1931; see p208 and 214 therein) gives orthogonal projections and even matrix units inside $\mathbb{C}S_n$ , cf https://mathoverflow.net/q/441536/.

It is not unimaginable for someone to independently discover this by trying to classify irreps of small examples, as long as they have the mental power to compute all the way up to $S_6$..

@JoshuaMundinger: Thanks for pointing this out! I was aware of the error in Vershik/Okounkov's III, but I didn't know that it had been inherited by Ceccherini-Silberstein/Scarabotti/Tolli (in the form of the false Lemma 3.6.4 in that book). So that's maybe not the best reference. That said, I don't know if they actually use the Frobenius-Young correspondence in the rest of the book, as the proof of Corollary 6.2.20 (which is saying that the Specht module constructed a la Okounkov-Vershik is isomorphic to the Specht module constructed a la Specht) seems to be independent of this.

@JulesLamers: Strictly speaking, the $c_\lambda$s are orthogonal (but not enough to span all copies of each irrep); it's the $c_T$s that are not (for different standard tableaux $T$ of the same shape). The nonzero products start at $n = 5$.

There is a way to motivate the construction of the Young symmetrisers, at least if you are willing to take Schur-Weyl duality as axiomatic.
Recall that we have commuting left $GL(V)$ and right $S_d$ actions on $V^{\otimes d}$. For the purposes of this post, Schur-Weyl duality refers to the decomposition of $V^{\otimes d}$ with as a $(GL(V), S_d)$-bimodule:
\begin{equation}
V^{\otimes d} = \bigoplus_{\lambda \vdash d} \mathbb{S}^\lambda(V) \otimes S^\lambda,
\end{equation}
where $S^\lambda$ is the Specht module associated to $\lambda$, and $\mathbb{S}^\lambda(V)$ is the Schur functor associated to $\lambda$ applied to $V$ (equivalently, the highest weight representation of $GL(V)$ of weight $\lambda$). See Digression A for further discussion.
One upshot of this is that since $\mathbb{S}^\lambda(V)$ contains a 1-dimensional highest-weight space of weight $\lambda$ (and no other $GL(V)$ irreducible does), the space of highest-weight vectors of weight $\lambda$ in $V^{\otimes d}$ is isomorphic as an $S_d$-module to $S^\lambda$. So let's try to understand this space a bit better. Let $\{e_i\}$ be a basis of $V$ (we are making a choice of Cartan).
First observation: the weight of $\{e_{a_1} \otimes e_{a_2} \otimes  \cdots \otimes e_{a_d}\}$ is $(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_d)$, where $n_i$ is the number of times $i$ appears in $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_d)$. All such tuples $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_d)$ differ only by a reordering of the entries, which is to say that the symmetric group acts transitively on them. The stabiliser is isomorphic to $S_{n_1} \times S_{n_2} \times \cdots \times S_{n_d}$.
We conclude in particular that the $\lambda$-weight space of $V^{\otimes d}$ is isomorphic to the permutation module $M^\lambda$ as an $S_d$-module. If we choose $v = e_1^{\otimes \lambda_1} \otimes e_2^{\otimes \lambda_2} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_d^{\otimes \lambda_d}$ as a generating vector, the stabiliser is precisely $P_{T_\lambda}$ as defined in your post.
Second observation: here is a construction of a highest-weight vector in $V^{\otimes d}$ of weight $\lambda$. Let
\begin{equation}
\wedge_r = \sum_{g \in S_r} sign(g) \left(e_{g(1)} \otimes e_{g(2)} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{g(r)} \right)
\end{equation}
be the wedge product of the first $r$ basis vectors, embedded in $V^{\otimes r}$; it is a highest weight vector of weight $(1^r)$. If $\lambda^\prime$ is the dual partition to $\lambda$, then $\bigotimes_{j=1}^{l(\lambda^\prime)} \wedge_{\lambda_j^\prime}$ being the the tensor product of highest weight vectors is itself highest weight of weight $\lambda$.
So to get from the weight vector $v = e_1^{\otimes \lambda_1} \otimes e_2^{\otimes \lambda_2} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_d^{\otimes \lambda_d}$ to a highest weight vector, we need to antisymmetrise. But the tensor factors that need to be antisymmetrised aren't contiguous for this vector: in fact the right antisymmetrising element is $b_\lambda$ as you defined it.
Now to combine these two observations: Note that $|P_{T_\lambda}| v = v a_\lambda$ (because $a_\lambda$ is up to rescaling the idempotent corresponding to the stabiliser subgroup of $v$), so that $|P_{T_\lambda}| v b_\lambda = v a_\lambda b_\lambda = v c_\lambda$ is a highest-weight vector of weight $\lambda$. By our Schur-Weyl duality argument, this vector generates the $S_d$ representation $S^\lambda$. So we have a surjective map $c_\lambda \mathbb{C}S_d \to S^\lambda$ defined by $c_\lambda x \mapsto v c_\lambda x$. It isn't immediately obvious that this map is injective; for that we have to do some extra work like what can be found in standard treatments of Young symmetrisers. But at least we have encountered the Young symmetriser in the wild. Strictly speaking, we've used right modules instead of left modules, but see Digression B to see that the difference is not material.
Digression A: The double-centraliser formulation of Schur-Weyl duality directly implies that $V^{\otimes d}$ decomposes as a direct sum of [irreducible of $GL(V)$]$\otimes$[irreducible of $S_d$], providing a perfect matching of $GL(V)$ irreducibles appearing in $V^{\otimes d}$ and $S_d$ irreducibles appearing in $V^{\otimes d}$. So we do not need to have studied Specht modules to make sense of the equation
\begin{equation}
V^{\otimes d} = \bigoplus_{\lambda \vdash d} \mathbb{S}^\lambda(V) \otimes S^\lambda,
\end{equation}
rather we can define $S^\lambda$ to be the irreducible corresponding to $\mathbb{S}^\lambda(V)$ in this perfect matching. By showing that $S^\lambda$ is isomorphic to $c_\lambda \mathbb{C}S_d$, we get that our $S^\lambda$ defined by Schur-Weyl duality is the same as the one defined by Young symmetrisers.
Digression B: Recall from Maschke's theorem and the Artin-Wedderburn theorem that we have $\mathbb{C}S_d = \bigoplus_V V \otimes V^* = \bigoplus_V End_\mathbb{C}(V)$ as a bimodule, where the sum is over all irreducible representations. The assertion that $c_\lambda \mathbb{C}S_d$ is irreducible implies that the decomposition of $c_\lambda = \bigoplus_V (c_\lambda)_V \in \bigoplus_V End_\mathbb{C}(V)$ has all components $(c_\lambda)_V$ equal to zero except for one that has rank one. This is because
\begin{equation}
c_\lambda \mathbb{C}S_d = \bigoplus_V (c_\lambda)_V V\otimes V^* = \bigoplus_V (V^*)^{\dim((c_\lambda)_V V)}
\end{equation}
Now, considering $\mathbb{C}S_d c_\lambda$ we multiply the same Artin-Wedderburn decomposition on the other side by a rank-one matrix to find that $\mathbb{C}S_d c_\lambda = V$ where $V^* = c_\lambda \mathbb{C}S_d$.
